# Simple LocalServer for test jwt (form register and login request)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Hi i need to do a webapp with user registration and I would like to try the script locally.
I do all site with Vue + Axios and I need to implement jwt.
Can someone let me how i can start locally server for test this script?

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    name: 'Register',
    data() {
        return {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            nome: '',
            cognome: '',
            data: '',
            telefono: '',
            risiedi: '',
            cap: '',
            provincia: '',
            citta: '',
            privacy: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handleSubmit() {
            const data = {
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password,
                nome: this.nome,
                cognome: this.cognome,
                data: this.data,
                telefono: this.telefono,
                risiedi: this.risiedi,
                cap: this.cap,
                provincia: this.provincia,
                citta: this.citta,
                privacy: this.privacy
            };
            axios.post('http://localhost:8000', data)
            .then(
                res => {
                    console.log(res)
                }
            ).catch(
                err => {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which language are you comfortable using? Node.js  - Express (a Node.js framework)? I can assist you with spinning this

Comment: yes Node it's perfect

Comment: what is your circumstance currently? do you want to continue development without waiting for your real backend to be ready? if its the case you can use mock server from postman

Comment: yes, I would like to continue to develop and test if the jtw code works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install a simple Node.js server using Express.js, first ensure that you have `express-generator` installed on your global `npm`. You can run the command below to install

```
npm install -g express-generator // may require (sudo) in some instances
```

Go to your desired project directory (e.g. `cd backend`), and **make sure it is empty**

```
.
├── frontend
├── backend
```

Then run the command

```
npx express-generator
```

Install the dependencies

```
npm install
```

Install cors

```
npm install cors
```

Set up cors (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) by opening `app.js`

```
// paste this at the top of the file
const cors = require('cors')

// then paste this somewhere after var app = express();
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:<Your_Frontend_Port>',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}
/* Enable CORS in the app */
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

Spin your server by running

```
npm start
```

You can now access your server by accessing

```
http://localhost:3000 // this is the default port
```

You can change the server port by defining a `.env` file and declaring `PORT=<Your_preferred_port>` and then running `npm install dotenv` before pasting `require('dotenv').config()` at the top of `bin/www`

You can modify the routes by access `routes/index.js` or `routes/users.js`. For example, to return `JSON` to the client, use `response.json({ yourKey: 'Your content' })` or `res.send({ name: 'MyName' })`. Both `.json` and `.send` are almost identical but we'll leave it here, for now.

Let us try an example route. Go to `routes/index.js` and add a route

```
/* GET name page */
router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({ testKey: 'Test content' })
});
```

On the frontend, do something like

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/test')
    .then(res => { console.log(res) })
    .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
```

To make your server reload immediately after making changes, install nodemon on the server

```
npm install nodemon -D
```

Go to the `package.json` and replace `"start": "node ./bin/www"` with `"start": "nodemon ./bin/www"`

Stop the server and run `npm start` once again

For more details, check the [express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html)

Comment: Thanks you so much, i will try soon

Comment: Great, should be quite friendly to set up

Comment: your setup is helpfully, but now i  receive the real backend and its setup with jwt. so i set all axios url and works fine but i need help to take token and state from email and send to verification API